# nodemon not restarting froze at "[nodemon] restarting due to changes..."

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, babeljs, nodemon

im having this issue, currenly im developing a express.js app with babel and nodemon. but resenly when i try to restart the server, it froze at [nodemon] restarting due to changes... and dosent restart. the command im using is npm run dev for develop. i tried every single solution "change to nodemon 2.0.7", "npm clean cache --force", "install @babel/cli, @babel/node, etc", "uninstall nodemon and then install it" and nothing work

Im using Windows 10 and .env files

**Console**

```
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `npx babel-node src/index.js`
Server listen on port 4000
Db is connected
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "scrap-api",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "babel src --out-dir build",
    "dev": "nodemon --exec npx babel-node src/index.js",
    "start": "node build/index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "core-js": "^3.22.5",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "helmet": "^5.0.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "pg": "^8.7.3",
    "regenerator-runtime": "^0.13.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.11",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0"
  }
}
```

**.babelsrc file**

```
    {
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"        
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/transform-runtime"]
    
}
```

right now is very frustrating because i have to stop the server and run it over and over again.

any sugestion apart of the mentioned, are welcome ):

Thanks!

Comment: finally i found another answer that worked for me

all i had to do was adding to my Windows "Enviroment Variables" the "system32 folder." if someone can explain my why this is necesary, would me a pleasure.

for someone who's having the same issue,here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9fIZViTNEA&ab_channel=TechTalkNetwork)!

Answer (score 0):

i'm have the same problem on windows 10
install 2.0.8 version and work!

```
npm install nodemon@2.0.8 -g
```